# Swift 4 Firebase Storage Metadata

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift4, firebase-storage

Can anyone help me in this problem . So I have a code for Firebase Storage using metadata, on Swift 4

Here is the code :

```
let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString

let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).png")

            if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileImageView.image!) {

                storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                    if error != nil {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }

                    if let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {

                        let values = ["name": name, "email": email, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]

                        self.registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid, values: values as [String : AnyObject])
                    }
                    print(metadata)
                })
```

and i have error in :
**if let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString**

the error :

> Value of type 'StorageMetadata?' has no member 'downloadURL'

This is the screenshot of my code
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WBPC.png)

Is there a solution , thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, it says metadata has no member downloadURL. so, it is removed from the StorageMetadata on firebase. You can do it like this.

```
let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString

let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).png")

        if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileImageView.image!) {

            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                guard let downloadURL = url else {
                    print("an error occurred!")

                    return
                }

                let profileImageUrl = downloadURL.absoluteString
                    let values = ["name": name, "email": email, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]

                    self.registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid, values: values as [String : AnyObject])

                print(metadata)
             }
            })
```

Detailed explanation is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files) at official doc

Try and share the results.

Comment: thanks for answer bhavin , but i still get the same error

Comment: Try now, I have edited the code. There was a typo. It should work now.

Comment: i think the downloadURL isn't in the same bracket , that cause unresolved identifier of downloadURL . But when i move it to same bracket the code is working , and the error is gone . thanks for the explanation bhavin